# Do CSS gradients get cached?

Tags: css, caching, gradient

my current project uses quite a few CSS-based background gradients. They are not used for every element, but they are quite essential for the User Interface.
While integrating them, I was unable to find detailed answers how these gradients affect performance.

Obviously having multiple gradients will use processing power when the respective element is first drawn. Is it known if this gradient generation can also be hardware-accelerated or is this CPU-only?

Additionally, and IMO more importantly, are they being cached? If so, what has to be identical for two elements to share the same "generated" gradient? My first guess would be that the css-statement and the element-size has to be identical (even if the classes that contain this statement are different). It could also be possible that it is being cached by class, but then the element-size could be different and as thus would require another gradient.

For example, if I have a list (ul) with let's say 15 list items (li), which each has a background gradient and includes three elements which also have background gradients, each element type has a constant size. Would the browser generate 15 or 60 gradients?

Comment: I think that the CSS caching is nothing but the caching of the CSS file so repeated download is not needed. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think that the styles must be rendered every time the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Pankucins is right - the browser will cache the whole CSS file when it is downloaded. The styles are then rendered when the page has loaded.

Each gradient will be rendered separately; but I really don't think it will be too much of a problem.

Comment: I doubt there is absolutely no caching of the generated images going on. While I did not check for it specifically, I am relatively sure that adding gradients increases the memory usage of the web application because some time before rendering it, it is created as a bitmap. I could be wrong, though ;)

Comment: If you were talking about the browser caching the bitmaps created by the gradient rule, then I'm 99.9% sure they aren't cached.

Comment: Well that sucks ;) isn't that horrendously inefficient?

Comment: I expect that it's probably too insignificant to matter - If you really needed to improve your site load time you could use a 1px by _x_ px gradient and repeat so that you are only loading one small image - but I expect this is what CSS gradient does anyway.